# Uploading to Amazon S3 from localhost

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tomcat7

I am trying to upload file to Amazon S3 using Tomcat 7 on my local machine. I get an error when I am trying to create a AmazonS3Client. The same code works fine in the desktop app.

```
String existingBucketName  = "namebucket"; 
String keyName             = "test.txt";
String filePath            = "C://test.txt";

AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("****","*********");
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);       
File file = new File(filePath);
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(existingBucketName, keyName, file));
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting Error 500:
"java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost:8084/tesapp/uploadservlet"

Comment: That looks like the error displayed in your browser. What is the actual error logged on the server side, in the Tomcat logs?

Comment: I am getting this message: "SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [UploadServlet] in context with path [/testapp] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.DnsResolver"

Comment: @M.Bystrov I'm guessing you are specifying a specific version of the Apache httpclient library, and the AWS SDK needs a newer version. Are you using a tool like Maven to manage your dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Maven and I'm using version 4.1.9 of the Apache httpclient.

Comment: I upload my application on Amazon and it works perfectly. Problem only with 'localhost'